# Sorting of Data grid view which is bound table

Tags: vb.net

**I want my first column sort of data grid view when form load**. but i have no code. Below i attach my loding code.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'EmployeeTBDataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.EmployeeTBDataSet.Table1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have presumably dragged a table from the Data Sources window onto your form to create that `DataGridView` and the code that populates the `DataTable` it is bound to.  That will also have created a `BindingSource` and that is where you perform most actions related to the bound data, including sorting.  After that call to `Fill`, set the `Sort` property of that `BindingSource` to the name of the column you want to sort by, e.g.

```
Me.Table1BindingSource.Sort = "Table1ID"
```

That will sort in ascending order implicitly.  You can also sort in ascending or descending order explicitly, e.g.

```
Me.Table1BindingSource.Sort = "Table1ID DESC"
```